# What are YouTube edit lists?

Tags: youtube

YouTube has the following site recommending the encoding settings:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en

I was wondering what they mean by "No Edit Lists" right at the start. I could not find *any* explanation online, except a short definition from the Apple Glossary. They say:

> edit list   A data structure that arranges a media into a time sequence.

I find this highly insufficient to understand exactly what it is.

Answer (score 4):

It seems edit lists are a Apple specific extension to the mp4 container format. The Edit List consists of Edit Atoms, which are segments (scenes if you will) in the video, which combined form the entire video. From the [Apple site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/qtff/QTFFChap2/qtff2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH204-BBCCFBEF):

> You use edit atoms to define the portions of the media that are to be
>   used to build up a track for a movie. The edits themselves are
>   contained in an edit list table, which consists of time offset and
>   duration values for each segment. Edit atoms have an atom type value
>   of 'edts'.

Comment: The Apple site also says "In the absence of an edit list, the presentation of a track starts immediately. An empty edit is used to offset the start time of a track.". Does this mean if there is an entry, it impacts PTS of the first frame? and it not PTS of 1st frame is 0?